# Finding sub-list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Pythonic way of expressing the simple problem:

> Tell if the list `needle` is sublist of `haystack`

---

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

def sublist (haystack, needle):

    def start ():
        i = iter(needle)
        return next(i), i

    try:
        n0, i = start()
        for h in haystack:
            if h == n0:
                n0 = next(i)
            else:
                n0, i = start()
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    return False
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: @JeffVanzella: Fair point. That's "code review". The question is: "what do you think in general?".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### 1. Bug

Here's a case where your function fails:

```
>>> sublist([1, 1, 2], [1, 2])
False
```

this is because in the `else:` case you go back to the beginning of the needle, but you keep going forward in the haystack, possibly skipping over a match. In the test case, your function tries matching with the alignment shown below, which fails at the position marked `X`:

```
             X
haystack   1,1,2
needle     1,2
```

Then it starts over from the beginning of the needle, but keeps going forward in the haystack, thus missing the match:

```
               X
haystack   1,1,2
needle         1,2
```

So after a mismatch you need to go *backward* an appropriate distance in the haystack before starting over again from the beginning of the needle.

#### 2. A better algorithm

It turns out to be better to start matching from the *end* of the needle. If this fails to match, we can skip forward several steps: possibly the whole length of the needle. For example, in this situation:

```
                  X
haystack  1,2,3,4,6,1,2,3,4,5
needle    1,2,3,4,5
```

we can skip forward by the whole length of the needle (because `6` does not appear in the needle). The next alignment we need to try is this:

```
                    O O O O O
haystack  1,2,3,4,6,1,2,3,4,5
needle              1,2,3,4,5
```

However, we can't always skip forward the whole length of the needle. The distance we can skip depends on the item that fails to match. In this situation:

```
                  X
haystack  1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5
needle    1,2,3,4,5
```

we should skip forward by 4, to bring the `1`s into alignment.

Making these ideas precise leads to the [Boyer–Moore–Horspool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore-Horspool_algorithm) algorithm:

```
def find(haystack, needle):
    """Return the index at which the sequence needle appears in the
    sequence haystack, or -1 if it is not found, using the Boyer-
    Moore-Horspool algorithm. The elements of needle and haystack must
    be hashable.

    >>> find([1, 1, 2], [1, 2])
    1

    """
    h = len(haystack)
    n = len(needle)
    skip = {needle[i]: n - i - 1 for i in range(n - 1)}
    i = n - 1
    while i < h:
        for j in range(n):
            if haystack[i - j] != needle[-j - 1]:
                i += skip.get(haystack[i], n)
                break
        else:
            return i - n + 1
    return -1
```

Comment: @Lattyware: Generally I'd agree that you should use iterators wherever it makes sense, but this is one of the exceptional cases where iterators don't make much sense. A pure-iterator search runs in O(*nm*) whereas Boyer–Moore-Horspool is O(*n*). (In the average case on random text.) Sometimes you just have to get your hands grubby.

Comment: Scratch all my arguments, it's impossible to do this correctly the way I was doing it.

Comment: Accepted. The source is strong with this one.

Comment: Does the dict comprehension overwrite previous values? If not you'll skip too far when you see `e` while searching for `seven`. I'd bet it does but am not sure. I do miss Python for its elegance.

Comment: Yes, later items in the dict comprehension override previous items, and so `find('seven', 'even')` → `1` as required.