# Longest Common Substring solution for a string and a list

Tags: python, algorithm, strings

Recently I have discovered one thing, which makes me feel frustrated. The Perl is lack of syntax sugar for strings, to do the same things, those are applicable to lists. The implementation I posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/56339/longest-common-substring-solution) would require to be rewritten to work for lists.

Thus, I had to re-write the code to Python to work for list as efficient as it does for strings:

```
def _contains(subseq, inseq):
    return any(inseq[pos:pos + len(subseq)] == subseq for pos in range(0, len(inseq) - len(subseq) + 1))

def lcss(s1, s2, threshold=3):

    all_of = []

    def is_inner_seq(i, j):
        return any(k < i < j <= l or k <= i < j < l for k, l in all_of)

    for i in range(0, len(s1)):
        for j in range(i + threshold, len(s1) + 1):

            if _contains(subseq=s1[i:j], inseq=s2):
                all_of.append((i, j))  # add a tuple to work OK when s1, s2 are lists

    only_outer_seq = filter(lambda tup: not is_inner_seq(tup[0], tup[1]),
                            all_of)

    return [s1[i:j] for i, j in only_outer_seq]
```

Here I implemented one minor improvement - filtering out inner substrings from the resultset, which aims to display more laconic result.

To not to frighten anyone with long sheets of code, here I am attaching a link to units tests, I used to tune up this solution: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aa7540cc7db2ca446e2b

Your comments are welcomed! Especially on function '_contains', which does not look like a simple way of doing a simple task. I have started studying the Python just a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No docstrings! What do your functions do and how do I call them?
2. Your `lcss` function has a name that suggests it might return the *longest* common subsequence. But in fact it returns *all* common subsequences of length 3 or more (except for ones that appear inside other common subsequences in `s1`). Is this really what you want the function to return? If so, you probably want to rethink the name.
3. [Python's `in` operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#in) already implements your `_contains` operation for strings:

   ```
   >>> [w.strip() for w in open('/usr/share/dict/words') if 'abc' in w]
   ['crabcatcher', 'dabchick']
   ```

   It's also much faster.
4. I guess you didn't use `in` because you want your subsequence operation to work on all kinds of sequence (not just strings). But in that case you should prefer to use one of the [Boyer–Moore search algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm), for example [Boyer–Moore–Horspool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer-Moore-Horspool_algorithm), so that the complexity is more like \$O(n)\$ (on average on random inputs) than \$O(mn)\$.

   See [this answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/19629/11728) for a Boyer–Moore–Horspool implementation in Python.
5. Your algorithm has complexity \$O(m^3n)\$ (where \$m\$ and \$n\$ are the lengths of the two sequences). But the longest common subsequence problem for two sequences has a well known \$O(mn)\$ algorithm, [described in detail in the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Solution_for_two_sequences).